# Как ввести строку в консоль js, и разбить её на две переменные

Tags: javascript, node.js

подскажите, как реализовать ввод двух чисел через запятую в консоль (node.js), и сделать из этих чисел две отдельные переменные? пытался сделать это через readline, но разбить на переменные не получилось, заранее спасибо

Comment: Результат из `readline` разбейте на отдельные подстроки функцией `str.split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

```
readlineInferfaceInstance.question('....', answer => {
  let [variableA, variableB] = answer.split(/,\s*/); 
  /* .... */
});
```

Вместо регулярки `/,\s*/` лучше использовать более гибкую `/[^\d.,-]+/` - с второй, разделителем может быть любой символ (или несколько символов) кроме числовых, точки, запятой, и дефиса/минуса. Пользователями часто предпочитается пробел в роли разделителя значений в строке (видимо, размер клавиши сказывается ).
*// Запятая у нас по стандарту является десятичным разделителем, если что... из-за этого, в качестве разделителя **значений**, она несет в себе потенциальную проблему (для пользователей). В программах для РФ и Европы (кроме UK), типкаст строки к `number` всегда лучше выполнять с `replace(',', '.')`, тем самым предусматривая использование юзером любого из двух вариантов десятичного разделителя в числах.*